# problem with r.quantile

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis

I would like to get the quantiles of a .jp2 raster by the following code, and write the results to a text file:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import processing
import gdal

fileName = "d:/bitbucket/cnn-lcm/T33TWM_A012703_20171127T100339_B04.jp2"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"

ext = rlayer.extent()
xmin = ext.xMinimum()
xmax = ext.xMaximum()
ymin = ext.yMinimum()
ymax = ext.yMaximum()
coords = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

layer = processing.getObject(rlayer.source())
processing.runalg("grass:r.quantile",fileName,5, "",coords,"","d:/bitbucket/cnn-lcm/T33TWM_A012703_20171127T100339_B04_q.txt")
```

If I call the procedure from Processing Toolbox GUI it works, but I have to solve it by script.

Error message:

> [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: '' See log for more details

Comment: i don't know that much of pyqgis but is the grass.script called by any of those libraries?

Comment: I don't have any issue with your code (except for third parameter that is boolean; not string). If you still experience problems, check your path file out carefully .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters for this processing tool are:

```
ALGORITHM: r.quantile - Compute quantiles using two passes.
    input <ParameterRaster>
    quantiles <ParameterNumber>
    -r <ParameterBoolean>
    GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
    html <OutputHTML>
    rawoutput <OutputFile>
```

So, you have one issue in your code: third parameter is boolean (not string).

I tried out a following modified version of your code (with my path to jp2 file):

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import processing
import gdal

fileName = "/home/zeito/S2A_MSIL1C_20170422T110651_N0204_R137_T30STF_20170422T111300.SAFE/GRANULE/L1C_T30STF_A009572_20170422T111300/IMG_DATA/T30STF_20170422T110651_B01.jp2"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"

ext = rlayer.extent()
xmin = ext.xMinimum()
xmax = ext.xMaximum()
ymin = ext.yMinimum()
ymax = ext.yMaximum()
coords = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

#layer = processing.getObject(rlayer.source()) not necessary line

processing.runalg("grass:r.quantile",
                  fileName,
                  5, 
                  False,
                  coords,
                  None,
                  "/home/zeito/S2A_MSIL1C_20170422T110651_N0204_R137_T30STF_20170422T111300.SAFE/GRANULE/L1C_T30STF_A009572_20170422T111300/IMG_DATA/T30STF_20170422T110651_B01.txt")
```

and I got a successful result for my text file after running it at Python Console of QGIS:

```
0:20.000000:1530.000000
1:40.000000:1636.000000
2:60.000000:1834.000000
3:80.000000:3477.000000
```

Comment: maybe, can you have a blink on this, I've just asked it now (it's related):
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266421/change-parameter-in-grass-processing-runalg-r-quantiles-quantile-to-percentile

Answer (score 0):

btw in `Qgis3.x` this becomes:

```py
qgis_proc.run(
   "grass7:r.quantile",
   parameters={
     'input': raster,
     'quantiles': 4,
     'percentiles': '',
     'bins': 1000000,
     '-r': True,
     'file': '/tmp/report.html',
     'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None,
     'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER': 0
   }
)
```